# I cant start apache after upgrading to yosemite

Tags: apache, localhost, osx-yosemite

I updated to Yosemite and when I type localhost into the browser It says webpage not availible. I tried restarting apache but it still wouldn't work. Does anyone have advice?

Here are my error logs:

```
[Tue Oct 21 20:04:25 2014] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 21 20:55:27 2014] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Cliffords-MacBook.local for ServerName
[Tue Oct 21 20:55:28 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Oct 21 20:55:28 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Oct 21 20:55:28 2014] [emerg] (17)File exists: Couldn't create accept lock (/private/var/log/apache2/accept.lock.22) (5)
[Tue Oct 21 20:55:29 2014] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Cliffords-MacBook.local for ServerName
[Tue Oct 21 20:55:29 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Oct 21 20:55:29 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Oct 21 20:55:29 2014] [warn] pid file /private/var/run/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Tue Oct 21 20:55:29 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.5.14 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 21 20:57:10 2014] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/favicon.ico
[Tue Oct 21 21:35:36 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Comment: I would start with the logs `/var/log/apache2/error_log`

Comment: here are my error logs: